Laravel + laravel-mongodb + lighthouse (graphql)?
Is there any way to use the Laravel 11 + Lighthouse-php + MongoDB (laravel-mongodb)?
I want to connect the Laravel 11 application with MongoDB atlas and fetch using GraphQL. I have already implemented with mysql instead of mongodb.

Yes there is, install https://github.com/mongodb/laravel-mongodb then you will update your models to use mongo instead of mysql with
use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model;
use MongoDB\Laravel\Relations\HasOne;

And then within the class add, making sure to add mongodb details to your config/database.php file
 protected  $connection = 'mongodb';

 protected  $collection = 'table';

